# How to choose the python interpreter of a ProcessPoolExecutor process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am making a program that runs processes in a ProcessPoolExecutor and returns the result once finished. The script I want to run uses pretty old libraries, so I don't want to have to include them in the main script. Instead, I have another virtual environment that is set up to run the subprocess.

I am using a ProcessPoolExecutor to spawn the jobs. How can I pick the python interpreter to use when running these jobs?

I saw that ProcessPoolExecutor has a `initargs` argument, but when I included it in my code:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(
        initargs=('PYTHONHOME', r'C:\Users\Tom.Mclean\Anaconda3\envs\weatherrouting_v1')) as pool:
    return await loop.run_in_executor(pool, fn, *args)
```

It just crashed.

EDIT:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
    pool._mp_context.set_executable(r'C:\Users\Tom.Mclean\Anaconda3\envs\weatherrouting_v2\python.exe')
    return await loop.run_in_executor(pool, fn, *args)
```

Comment: ``initargs`` are for the ``initializer`` function. Both are used *after* the process has started so they are not suitable for what you want to do.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Hmm, seems what I want is equivalent to the `multiprocessing.set_executable()` function, is there an equivalent for `ProcessPoolExecutor`?

Comment: In a way, yes. You can provide a ``multiprocessing`` context with custom executable to ``ProcessPoolExecutor``. However, I just tried that with CPython 3.9 to PyPy 3.7 – starting the processes works but the parts of ``concurrent.futures`` are different enough to break things immediately.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The edit I made on my question works for me, does it work for you?

Comment: It only works if both Python's are compatible with the main process' ``concurrent.futures``. So it'll work if you have another venv of the same Python version but most likely not across Python versions.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks, They are both python3, its just that the job I am spawning uses BaseMap and I don't want to have to import that because it makes solving the environment hard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide a `multiprocessing` context with explicit executable to the Pool.

```py
import multiprocessing
import concurrent.futures

if __name__ == "__main__":
    context = multiprocessing.get_context('spawn')
    context.set_executable(...)  # <<< set worker executable

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(mp_context=context) as pool:
        ...
```

Note that `concurrent.futures` initialises the worker processes based on the parent process' `concurrent.futures` library. This means the executable must be able to parse and run the library in the *parent process*' version.
As a result, this can e.g. be used with a different venv using the same Python version. It cannot be used to run a significantly older version of Python, such as a parent process of Python 3.9 and worker process of Python 3.7.